# How to convert an string to json in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert an string into `json` output from **local Data** or Those datas from `BeautifulSoup` output as `Json`.for example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

data = ('Hello')
print data
```

and i need to convert this `Hello` as json output.

How can do that?

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#module-json) module to encode Python objects as JSON, e.g.

```
>>> import json
>>> data = ('Hello')
>>> json.dumps(data)
'"Hello"'

>>> data = ('Hello', 'There')
>>> json.dumps(data)
'["Hello", "There"]'


>>> data = {'message': 'Hello'}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"message": "Hello"}'
```

Comment: thanks.but it seems it doesnt work on these codes: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12134971/

Comment: When I run the linked code it outputs this JSON encoded string: `'"\\u062a\\u0644\\u06af\\u0631\\u0627\\u0645 \\u0628\\u0631\\u0627\\u06cc \\u0633\\u06cc\\u0645\\u0628\\u06cc\\u0646 \\u0648 \\u062c\\u0627\\u0648\\u0627 !\\u0627\\u0635\\u0627 \\u062f\\u0627\\u0631\\u06cc\\u0645 \\u061f\\u061f\\u061f"'`. It is only displaying the last one in the `title_rows` list, but it does appear to work.

Comment: yeah, lets try it with english words.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Do you want a JSON encoded list of URLs? If you are trying to extract the URL, try `json.dumps(texts.a['href'])`, e.g.`'"showthread.php?148784-\\u062a\\u0644\\u06af\\u0631\\u0627\\u0645-\\u0628\\u0631\\u0627\\u06cc-\\u0633\\u06cc\\u0645\\u0628\\u06cc\\u0646-\\u0648-\\u062c\\u0627\\u0648\\u0627-!\\u0627\\u0635\\u0627-\\u062f\\u0627\\u0631\\u06cc\\u0645-\\u061f\\u061f\\u061f&s=a3e13225636cf0a310f89089f1b61161&goto=newpost"'`

Comment: actually i was trying to achieve this persian words into json, but it seems its returns last one as json:-?

Comment: Only the last one is converted to JSON because `print json.dumps(txt)` is outside of the preceding for loop. If you want all converted to JSON then move the print statement within the body of the loop.Since you want the text, not the URL, you can do this: `json.dumps([texts.get_text('a', 'href') for texts in title_rows])` . This will give you a JSON encoded list of the text from each link.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the json module in Python https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
import json
json.dumps({"hello": 0}, sort_keys=True)
```